# How to get all menu items programmatically in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a static method `InflateToolbarMenu` that accept an activity and populate menu items for it. This method will be called on Activity.OnCreateOptionsMenu of all my activities to get me a globally accessible menu.

How do I get all items in the `menu` of type `Imenu` after inflating?
I want to traverse them and set all of them a listener. I don't want to do it in Activity.OnCreateOptionsMenu because this is a menu of a globally visible toolbar that acts the same way in any activity.

In my MenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener I'm using a switch statement, so that the code looks good.

Now I'm doing:

```
    public static void InflateToolbarMenu(this AppCompatActivity activity, IMenu menu)
    {
        activity.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.toolbar_menu_common, menu);         
        menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.menu_item_1).SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener());
        menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.menu_item_2).SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener());    
        ...                  
        menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.menu_item_N).SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener());
    }
```

What I want is like

```
    menu.ForEach(m=>m.SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is doing something like this:

Assuming there is an `IMenu` by the name of `Menu`

```
var listMenuItems = new List<IMenuItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < Menu.Size(); i++)
{
   listMenuItems.Add(Menu.GetItem(i)); // here you can add them into a list of items if you want
   Menu.GetItem(i).SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener());
}
```

As of with the peace of code you have added it is not possible as IMenu does not have a definition for `GetEnumerator` which means its not a generic collection and cannot be looped on directly.

Comment: Well It's that simple! No wonder nobody asked this question. I traversed through all the properties of the type and tried `Count` and `Length` and other common names from the Linq family, god knows how I have overlooked `Size`... Although a Enumerator implementation would've been great.

Comment: Well, the problem here is that you are looking into properties as per the `Linq` and `C#` naming convention whereas `Android` is more about `Java` and hence the name `Size`, Also `Enumerator` would help but you well what can we do!!

Comment: You're exactly right. My mindset has been revolving around .NET too long and it need some change :) Thanks mate.

Comment: No problem Goodluck!